# javascript array combine variable values

Tags: javascript, variables

I am having trouble finding the correct wording to find the answer.
I am trying to combine elements in an array.

```
 array[0] = "bob";
 array[1] = "john";
 array[2] = "frank";

 for (i = 0;i<array.length;i++)
 {
 (in php i would use .=)
     var list .= array[i]+"<br>";
 }
```

What do i replace .= with?

Comment: += in Javascript is the same as .= in php. You just need to be careful with ints and strings

Comment: Also you forgot to declare `i`.

Comment: look at my answer, I give you 2 options to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `.join()`

```
array.join('</br>')
```

Comment: In php as well (`implode`), no loops required.

Comment: `</br>`? Are you sure about that? I *hope* you meant: `<br />`

Comment: yup.. `</br>` or `<br />` or `<br>`  should do.. but eventually is depends on DOCTYPE though..

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

```
 array[0] = "bob";
 array[1] = "john";
 array[2] = "frank";
 array.join('</br>')
```

And if you do want to keep with your loop then use the `+=` operator:

```
 var list = '';
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
 {
     list += array[i]+"<br/>";
 }
```